# Html.actionlink is not generating correct url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My route in global.asax in like this-

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "History", // Route name
            "{controller}/{PageID}/{LanguageID}/{PreviousRevisionID}/{NewRevisionID}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserArea", action = "Index", PageID = 0, LanguageID = 0, PreviousRevisionID = 0, NewRevisionID = 0} // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I am using Html.actionLink to make url Like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.CreatedTS.ToString(), "Index", new { PageID = item.PageID ,LanguageID = item.LanguageID , PreviousRevisionID = item.PreviousRevisionID , NewRevisionID = item.NewRevisionID , controller = "History" });
```

But the url generate like This

```
http://localhost:2582/History?PageID=2&LanguageID=3&PreviousRevisionID=98&NewRevisionID=103
```

But I want url Like this

```
http://localhost:2582/History/2/3/98/103
```

Where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx) instead of ActionLink:

```
@Html.RouteLink(item.CreatedTS.ToString(), "History", new { PageID = item.PageID ,LanguageID = item.LanguageID , PreviousRevisionID = item.PreviousRevisionID , NewRevisionID = item.NewRevisionID , controller = "History" });
```

For the differences see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may have your routes defined in the wrong order.  You want this route to be defined before the default route.  So your routes may look something like this.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "History", // Route name
            "{controller}/{PageID}/{LanguageID}/{PreviousRevisionID}/{NewRevisionID}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserArea", action = "Index", PageID = 0, LanguageID = 0, PreviousRevisionID = 0, NewRevisionID = 0 } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

The route debugger utility by Phil Haack is very helpful for debugging routes.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

PM> Install-Package routedebugger

Comment: I added a link to a route debugger.  Is the correct route getting chosen?