# ASP.NET MVC3 not right index page because of routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have these routes:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                 "ActionOnly",
                 "{action}",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 new { action = "Klub|Historie" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Administrace", // Route name
                "Administrace/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Administrace", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            // Hrac/Jmeno_hrace
            routes.MapRoute(
                 "Hrac",
                 "Hrac/{name}",
                 new { Controller = "Hrac", Action = "Name" }
            );


            // pro aktivaci uzivatele který se registroval, ale jeste nepotvrdil email
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Activate",
                "Account/Activate/{username}/{key}",
                new { controller = "Account", action = "Activate", username = UrlParameter.Optional, key = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Why  `@Html.ActionLink("Domů", "Index", "Home")` is creating website.com/Administrace/Home and not website.com/Home/index and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try using @Html.RouteLink instead with the route being default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Administrace` route is swallowing all controllers.

You should change it to hard-code the controller name:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Administrace", // Route name
    "Administrace/Administrace/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Administrace", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

If you want that route to work for multiple controllers, you should replace it with an area (or just add a constraint).

Comment: Area looks good but I have little problem with Ninject. It´s not returning controller for my route. Should I change something in ninject?

Comment: I don't know; search Google for `ninject asp.net mvc areas`

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.RouteLink instead with the route name being `default`

Link to something that might help:
[What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: thanks for routelink, it´s working, if I don´t use area from other post, I´ll accept yours :)