# Difference between RouteLink and ActionLink() in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

What's the difference between `RouteLink()` and `ActionLink()` in *ASP.NET MVC*?

When to use use `Html.RouteLink()` and when to use `Html.ActionLink()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ActionLink` method renders an element that links to an action method.

The `RouteLink` method renders an element that links to a URL, which can resolve to an action method, a file, a folder, or some other resource.

Answer (score 0):

[What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

This question has been answered already, I'm not going to steal it's contents.

Comment: i reckon it's an exact duplicate of that question, would vote to close.

Comment: I think I don't have enough points to vote for closure, thanks