# When to use Html.RouteLink() and difference against Html.ActionLink()

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and came across this particular Html Helper method.

When would one use

`@Html.RouteLink("Routed Link", new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id="MyID"})`

What is the difference between this and `Html.ActionLink()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionLink is a specific way to link to a specific action by specifying the action and controller.  [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) gives you more control over the routing.  For instance, look at [this override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492904%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which gives you the most flexibility in generating a URL, not necessarily tied to an action.

Answer (score 1):

According to: [What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

> ActionLink will generate the URL to get to an action using the first
>   matching route by action name.
>
> RouteLink will generate a URL to a specific route determined either by
>   name or route values.