# Routing ASP NET with two parameters not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have read here : [Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc). But still not worked in my case.

I have `EmitenController` which there a function like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Financial(string q = null, int page = 1)
```

At first load, the URL that produced by this function: `Emiten/Financial?q=&page=1`.
The next page of course `Emiten/Financial?q=&page=2`.

If I give the query that URL become: `Emiten/Financial?q=query&page=1` and go on.

For the routes, I have tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Financial",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{q}/{page}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Emiten", action = "Financial", q = "", page = 1 }
);
```

But, when I try go to page 3 the URL still `Emiten/Financial?q=&page=2` and how about the URL if I give `q` empty value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the route is for a specific action method, then you should specify the action method directly in the URL settings

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Financial",
   url: "Emiten/Financial/{q}/{page}", // <---- Right here
   defaults: new 
   { 
       controller = "Emiten", 
       action = "Financial", 
       q = string.Empty, // string.Empty is the same as ""
       page = 1,
   }
);
```

In your action method, you don't need to specify the default values since you already did that in your route config.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Financial(string q, int page)
```

Let me know how it works for you

**UPDATE:**

Generating a link relative to a route

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    linkText: "Next Page", 
    routeName: "Financial", 
    routeValues: new { controller = "Emiten", action = "Financial", q = ViewBag.SearchKey, page = nextPage})
```

Related Link: [What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The constraints seem a little redundant as the method will throw an exception that you passed it an invalid value, which might be more useful then getting a 404 for not matching any routes.

Comment: @siva.k - Thanks for that, I removed it.

Comment: @andrefadila Did you try to manually type the url? Can you show us the method you used to generate the url?

Comment: Oh I see, I am using this `@Url.Action("Financial", "Emiten", new { q = ViewBag.SearchKey, page = nextPage })` (nextPage is number) for href attribute on link next page. What should I use?

Comment: @andrefadila - I have updated my answer to show how to generate a route link.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue. Are you sure you mapped your Financial route before your Default one?

Here is my RegisterRoutes method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Financial",
        "{controller}/{action}/{q}/{page}",
        new { controller = "Emiten", action = "Financial", q = string.Empty, page = 1 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public class EmitenController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Financial(string q, int page)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

(I know the async is useless in this case, but you can't await a ViewResult)
And here is the View:

```
q = @Request.QueryString["q"]<br/>
page = @Request.QueryString["page"]

@Html.ActionLink("Page 2", "Financial", "Emiten", new { q = "test", page = 2 }, null)
<br/>
<a href="@Url.Action("Financial", "Emiten", new { q = "test", page = 3 })">Page 3</a>
```

Everything works as expected