# MVC ActionLink appending route as querystring rather than route values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I have an MVC Action Link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update Information", "Index", "Performance", 
new { performanceid = item.PerformanceId }, null)
```

This action link's href looks like this: /Performance/Index?performanceid=100

In my RouteConfig.cs I have the following routes in the following order:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "ShowPerformanceOptions",
      "Performance/{performanceid}/Index",
      new { controller = "Peformance", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I do not want a querystring added to the end of the URL, I would instead like the URL to look like this: /Performance/360/Index

I have been through a variety of different options including adding the route parameters and optional url parameters and changing the way I write my ActionLink. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You're having a typo in the default route params defintion, it's `Peformance` instead of `Performance`.

Comment: This also works! Good spot, I thought there must have been something wrong for it not to recognise any of my routes that I had specified! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To generate URL based on *route name*, use [`Html.RouteLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.RouteLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29)  method

```
@Html.RouteLink("Update Information", "ShowPerformanceOptions", new { performanceid = item.PerformanceId })
```

A good read [What's the difference between RouteLink and ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864827/whats-the-difference-between-routelink-and-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Actually, `ActionLink` *should* have used the specified pattern as well.

Comment: @haim770, Yep even that would work but I am not sure it will generate anchor tag

Comment: @Satpal, I meant `ActionLink` and it *will* generate the `<a>`. I assume the real problem is the typo in the route definition: `Peformance` instead of `Performance`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Satpal pointed out, the ActionLink wasn't working because of the typo in the route itself:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "ShowPerformanceOptions",
      "Performance/{performanceid}/Index",
      new { controller = "**Peformance**", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
      "ShowPerformanceOptions",
      "Performance/{performanceid}/Index",
      new { controller = "**Performance**", action = "Index" }
);
```